# Having trouble creating calculator with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new no Python and we have a project to create a calculator. I've been following videos online since even this is the first time they teach that class and even the professor is lost. I was following some code online but at some point I'm getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'input_value'

Any idea what might be the issue, thanks. This is fragment of the code.

```
calc = Frame(gui)
calc.grid()

class Calc():
    def _init_(self):
        self.total =0
        self.current =""
        self.input_value = True
        self.checkSum = False
        self.op =""
        self.result = False

    def numberEnter(self, num):
        self.result = False
        firstNumb =txtDisplay.get()
        secondNumb= str(num)
        if self.input_value:
            self.current = secondNumb
            self.input_value = False
        else:
            if secondNumb == '.':
                if secondNumb in firstNumb:
                    return
                self.current = firstNumb + secondNumb
        self.display(self.current)


    def display(self, value):
        txtDisplay.delete(0, END)
        txtDisplay.insert(0, value)


addedValue = Calc() 

txtDisplay = Entry(calc, font = ('arial',20,'bold'), bg ="light blue", bd =30, width =32, justify =RIGHT)
txtDisplay.grid(row=0, column =0, columnspan =5)
txtDisplay.insert(0,"0")

numbersCalc = "789456123"
i = 0
cnp = []
for j in range(2,5):
    for k in range(3):
        cnp.append(Button(calc, width =6, height =2,font = ('arial',20,'bold'),bd =4, text =numbersCalc[i]))
        cnp[i].grid(row =j, column = k, pady =0)
        cnp[i] ["command"] = lambda x =numbersCalc[i]: addedValue.numberEnter(x)
        i += 1


button0 = Button(calc, text ="0", width = 6, height =2, font = ('arial',20,'bold'),bd =4, background ="light blue",command = lambda: addedValue.numberEnter(0))
button0.grid(row =  5, column = 0)
```

Comment: It's `__init__`, not `_init_`. (2 underscores)

Answer (score 0):

you have written `_init_` (one underscore in the class), but instead it is should be `__init__`.

Change your code to `def __init__(self):`

Comment: Thanks, works now. Any idea why it won't take more than one number in the input?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the indent of the last line in the following:

```
    else:
        if secondNumb == '.':
            if secondNumb in firstNumb:
                return
        self.current = firstNumb + secondNumb # <= this line
            # from here
        # to here is a decrease in indent
```

To allow it to append additional digits.